# Event registration allows free registrations (but shouldn't)

Tags: civievent

We have 2 price levels for our events: adult and child but cannot make either of them required as it is possible in our case to register either a child, or an adult. We use the numeric/quantity fields. Some people hit "register" without filling in anything and get through to the confirmation screen. In the back-end the registration shows up with a "registered" status and "attendee" role and payment amount "$0". How can this be prevented?

Joomla 3.4.8
CiviCRM 4.6.10

http://www.nywolf.org/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=350

I'm not allowed to post more than 1 image so here's the back-end:

[image: Back end]

Comment: Please add civi version, CMS and CMS version and if possible give screenshots of registration page and priceset configuration pages.

Comment: We're having exactly the same problem - did you find a fix?

Comment: We haven't found a fix using the setup we currently have in place. We're using the pre-form text to remind registrants that they need to enter a number in the quantity field. So far this has stopped the $0 registrations but it's not a solution, just a workaround for now.

Answer (score 5):

A way to do this would be the following:

- Enable in the Event Configuration the option "Register multiple participants?"
- Use in the priceset a radio button for child/adult. You can make it required and add a different price for each.

You will have the option to set a different "Profile for Additional Participants", so you can collect different data for the person entering the form compared to the other participants.

That way you know who will attend the course and know per registrant whether it is a child or parent.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in 4.7.14: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19626.